# index out of bound while looping through a list and deleting some of the elements in python

Tags: python, loops, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to loop through a list of numbers from 2 to 10000 and delete the mutliples of 2,3,4, and to 100 but not these numbers but everytime i delete an item the length of the list shrinks so it produces an index out of bound error how do i fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please include your code as **text** in the question itself, not as an image.

Comment: 1) don't paste images of your code. Just paste the code in and format it. 2) don't delete the data as you iterate. Maybe make an empty array and insert into that. 3) what is your end goal? Maybe look into a list comprehension as you iterate through the range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that might work for you.
It leverages list comprehension.
I didn't quite understand your code, especially the index increment in the `while` loop that only runs until multiple is 101.

```
def is_multiple(number):
    for m in range(2, 101):
        if number is not m and number % m == 0:
            return True


numbers = range(2, 10000)

numbers = [n for n in numbers if not is_multiple(n)]

print(numbers)
```